# Checkbox Command/IsChecked execution order

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a CheckBox like this-

```
 <CheckBox Command="{Binding Command1}"
           CommandParameter="{Binding }"
           IsChecked="{Binding Prop1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

When I click it - the IsChecked binding is triggered before the Command execution. It doesn't look like it's due to the order they appear in xaml(I can change it and the execution order stays the same).

Now I'm wondering - is there any place that documents the order of execution for Bindings/Commands? Or maybe there's just a simple guiding rule?

Can I count on the IsChecked binding to always trigger before the Command?

Comment: I don't know if there is any documentation detailing this (have you checked the documentation for the `Command` and `IsChecked` property?), but think practically: If the command would be executed before setting the `IsChecked` property, the command (and all the code invoked by the command) would still see the checkbox in its old state and not in its current state. Wouldn't make much sense...

Comment: "_Can I count on the IsChecked binding to always trigger before the Command?_" Yes, you can. See the reference source code for ToggleButton: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ToggleButton.cs,263

Comment: (By the way, note that the command will not be triggered if you change the `IsChecked` property through the data binding. The command will only be triggered by whatever is considered to be a "click"/"press" of the button)